# Grouping arbitrary arrays of data into N bins

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I want to group an arbitrary-sized array of random values into `n` groups, such that the sum of values in any one group/bin is as equal as possible.

So for values `[1, 2, 4, 5]` and `n = 2`, the output buckets should be `[sum(5+1), sum(4+2)]`.

Some possibilities that occur to me:

- Full exhaustive breadth first search
- Random processes with stopping conditions hard coded
- Start from one end of the sorted array, grouping until the sum is equal to the global average, and move to the next group until `n` is reached

Seems like the optimal solution (where the sum of the contents of the bins are as equal as possible given the input array) is probably non-trivial; so at the moment I'm leaning towards the last option, but have the feeling I am possibly missing more elegant solutions?

Comment: This is kind of similar to the [bin packing  problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing) and the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).  You might want to make it explicit what you mean by 'as equal as possible'.

Comment: Yes, but was hoping it might be different in a way that might make a nice solution possible. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an NP-hard problem. In other words, it's not possible to find an optimal solution without exploring all combinations, and the number of combinations is n^M (where M is the size of you array, and n the number of beans). It's a problem very similar to *[clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)*, which is also NP-hard.

If your data set is small enough to deal with, a brute force algorithm is best (explore all combinations).

However, if your data set is big, you'll want a polynomial-time algorithm that won't get you the optimal solution, but a good approximation. In that case, I suggest you use something similar to *[K-Means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)*...

Step 1. Calculate the expected sum per bin. Let *A* be your array, then the expected sum per bin is *SumBin = SUM(A) / n*  (the sum of all elements in your array over the number of bins).

Step 2. Put all elements of your array in some collection (e.g. another array) that we'll call *The Bag* (this is just a conceptual, so you understand the next steps).

Step 3. Partition *The Bag* into *n* groups (preferably randomly, so that each element ends up in some bin *i* with probability 1/*n*). At this point, your bins have all the elements, and *The Bag* is empty.

Step 4. Calculate the sum for each bin. If result is the same as last iteration, **exit**. (this is the *expectation* step of *K-Means*)

Step 5. For each bin *i*, if its sum is greater than *SumBin*, pick the first element greater than *SumBin* and put it back in *The Bag*; if its sum is less than *SumBin*, pick the first element less than *SumBin* and put back in *The Bag*. This is the gradient descent step (aka *maximization* step) of *K-Means*.

Step 6. Go to step 3.

This algorithm is just an approximation, but it's fast and guaranteed to converge.

If you are skeptical about a randomized algorithm like the above, after the first iteration when you are back to step 3, instead of assigning elements randomly, you can do so optimally by running the *[Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)*, but I am not sure that will guarantee better over-all results.

Comment: Assuming that `P != NP`, you should add :P